# How to use href to pass value on another page?

Tags: asp.net

I have images which I am using to navigate to next page using href:

```
<a class="ajaxcolorbox" href="User.aspx">
```

Now I also want to pass some values so that I can display on some information depending on which image user has clicked.

Comment: Query strings are indeed your friend as the answers have pointed out. In addition, keep in mind [Cross Site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)), which could be used to manipulate parts of your page or even mess with your DB queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the query string.

```
<a class="ajaxcolorbox" href="User.aspx?id=<YOUR_ID>">
```

It is the easiest method to pass data around.

You can read it back on User.aspx as follows:

```
var id = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use QueryString as Id

User.aspx?imageId=value

and read it from the next page